# Invoking a web service from AJAX doesn't work in Internet Explorer

Tags: ajax, web-services

I've a little piece of code that invoke a web service and it works right when I use it in Firefox or Chrome, but nothing work when I use it in Internet Explorer.

Here you are my code

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Parsing XML Test</title>
  <style>
   body {
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
   }
   html, body, #map {
               height: 100%;
   }
  </style>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>   
  <script>
    function initialize() {  
        var query = 'service_url';
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: query,
          dataType: 'xml',
          success: function (data) {
                      alert("OK")
          },
          error: function (response, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(errorThrown);
                }
        });           
 }
  </script>   
 </head>
 <body onload="initialize()">
  <div id="map"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone help me to correct the code?

Thank you very much in advance!!

Cesare

Answer (score 0):

I've solved in this manner ...

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Parsing XML Test</title>
  <style>
    body {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
    html, body, #map {
               height: 100%;
    }
 </style>

 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>   

 <script>
   function initialize() {  
    var browser = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    var isIE = (browser.indexOf("msie")>-1 || browser.indexOf("trident")>-1);              
    if (isIE && window.XDomainRequest) {
                    if (window.XDomainRequest) {
                        var query = 'service_url';
                        var xdr = new XDomainRequest();
                        if (xdr) {
                            xdr.onload = function () {
                                alert("OK");
                                alert(xdr.responseText);
                            }
                            xdr.onerror = function () { 
                                alert("KO");
                            }
                            xdr.open('GET', query);
                            xdr.send();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    var query = var query = 'service_url';
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: query,
                        dataType: "text",
                        crossDomain: true,
                        success: function (data) {
                                               alert("OK");
                                               alert(data);
                        },
                        error: function (response, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            alert("KO");
                            alert(errorThrown);
                        }
                    });
                }
   }
 </script>   
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
 <div id="map"></div>
</body>
```

Now it's working on all the browsers!

I hope this could be useful ..